# How do you capture events from inside a Ractive Component's {{>content}} partial?

Tags: ractivejs

Lets say I have a modal component defined which defines a container for other content inside the modal window.

I can define that content with the {{>content}} partial, but if any of that content contains events like on-click, I can't capture that event from the Ractive that defines that content.

I can only capture those events from the component.

Is there anyway to make this work?

Comment: https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/2793#issuecomment-264889953

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only possible way is to manually bubble the events:

```html
<modal on-a="b">
    <div on-click="a">Click Me!</div>
</modal>
```

```js
ractive.on('b', function () {});
```

We are currently discussing [event bubbling](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/pull/1117) and [{{yield}}](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/pull/1141) keyword which will help in situations like this.